# customize button for JQuery Form Plugin

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-forms-plugin

I've got a form in which I upload a file using the JQuery Form Plugin. I would like to customize the upload button and have it submit onchange. Below you can see that I've hidden the form and replaced it with the #upfile1 link.

```
<form id="dataform" action="submit" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <a href="#" id="upfile1">Import .csv</a>
    <input type="file" name="myfile" id="myFile" style="display:none" onchange='this.form.submit()'/>
</form>
```

Then in my JQuery, I simulate clicking the form with this:

```
$("#upfile1").click(function () {
    $("#myFile").trigger('click');
});
```

However, it appears that mixing this and the JQuery Form Plugin doesn't work. The page loads again with "/submit" added to the end of the URL.

Here is the JQuery from the Form Plugin:

```
(function() {

var bar = $('.bar');
var percent = $('.percent');
var status = $('#status');

$('#dataform').ajaxForm({
    beforeSend: function() {
        status.empty();
        var percentVal = '0%';
        bar.width(percentVal)
        percent.html(percentVal);
    },
    uploadProgress: function(event, position, total, percentComplete) {
        var percentVal = percentComplete + '%';
        bar.width(percentVal)
        percent.html(percentVal);
    },
    success: function(data) {
        var percentVal = '100%';
        bar.width(percentVal)
        percent.html(percentVal);

       //Do some stuff

    },
complete: function(xhr) {
    status.html(xhr.responseText);
}
//
}); 
return false;
})();
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to submit the form, not the input.  Try this:

```
$("#upfile1").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#dataform").submit();
});
```

The documentation for jQuery's submit can be found [here](http://api.jquery.com/submit/).

I better understand your question, sorry for the confusion!  The html:

```
<input type="file" id="fileInput" multiple>
<button id="fileButton">Select some files</button>
```

The jQuery:

```
document.querySelector('#fileButton').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    // Use the native click() of the file input.
    document.querySelector('#fileInput').click();
}, false);
```

The CSS:

```
#fileInput { visibility:hidden; }
```

The [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mathieujonson/vJ3v9/).

Obviously, add the styles you want to make it look nice.

Comment: thanks! It didn't work though. It submits the form before I have a chance to choose the file I'm trying to upload. Any thoughts?

Comment: I updated the answer.  The e.preventDefault() will stop the form submission on the click.  Check and validate, and then run the .submit().  Let me know if it works.

Comment: I misunderstood part of the question.  The new answer should get you to where you want to go.  If not, let me know!